# How to sign X509 certificate requests by using java API?

Tags: java, certificate, x509

My java program should sign received X509 certificate requests by using own key.
Certificate requests are in PEM format. The key/certificate for signing is in the local java key store.

I have seek suitable classes from `java.security` package. But without success.

What classes of Java API should be used for signing X509 certificates?

I can convert PEM to DER, but decoding of DER causes problems.
I have tried the following:

```
BufferedInputStream  bis  = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(derReq));          
CertificateFactory certFact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");          
java.security.cert.Certificate cert = certFact.generateCertificate(bis);
```

And

```
javax.security.cert.X509Certificate cer = X509Certificate.getInstance(derReq);
```

Both will cause the following exception:

```
javax.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Empty input
```

So, seems that those are only for signed certificates, and not for X509 certificate requests.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any *PKI* with Java, but of course it usually remains the same. Check out this link: [PKI Java](http://www.mayrhofer.eu.org/create-x509-certs-in-java)

It covers the necessities for both **JCE** and **BC**.

Comment: The link here is broken.